# Does C. Difficile disappear completely?

Tags: clostridium-difficile

I have the chance to care (including changing diapers) for a disabled individual who previously had c diff, and was told he "no longer has it", but was later told it was only in remission.

He is on medication so that he "will never get it again". I've been told by some that this is a low risk situation, and by others that this is a very big deal.

Does c diff disappear completely? I know that many people have it in safe amounts in their stomachs. Can it be held in remission permanently with medication?

I am young and healthy, but taking antibiotics. I live with an individual whose career could end if he got c diff from me. I'm getting a lot of mixed messages, can someone help me understand this situation?